# How can I tokenize a text column in R? unnest function not working

Tags: r, text, token, tidytext

I am a new R user. Will really appreciate if you can help me with solving the tokenization problem:

**My task in brief:**
I am trying to import a text file in into R. One of the text columns is Headline. The dataset is basically a collection of news articles related to a disease.

**Issue:**
I have tried many times to tokenize it using the unnest_tokens function.

It is showing me the following error messages:

**Error in UseMethod("unnest_tokens_") : 
  no applicable method for 'unnest_tokens_' applied to an object of class "character"**

**Error in unnest_tokens(word, Headline) : object 'word' not found**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)

DengueNews %>%
unnest_tokens(word, Headline)
```

Note: 
Link of the dataset:https://drive.google.com/file/d/18VWg-2sO11GpwxMGF1UbziodoWK9B9Ru/view?usp=sharing
I am following the instructions from https://www.tidytextmining.com/tidytext.html

Comment: make sure that DenbueNews$Headline is not a factor. It needs to be a character column.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt reply. I have tried using the as.character function to convert. Now it is showing a new error message: Error in check_input(x) : 
  Input must be a character vector of any length or a list of character
  vectors, each of which has a length of 1

Comment: @BangladeshiVoice  Can you try the solution posted below.  I used the same data from the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear how the data was read.  As mentioned in the comments, if the data column 'Headline' is `character` class, it should work.  Here, we use `read_excl` from `readxl` package to read the dataset.  By default, columns that are `character` will be returned with `character` class attribute.

```
library(readxl)
library(tidytext)
DengueNews <- read_excel("DengueNews.xlsx")
class(DengueNew$Headline)
#[1] "character"

DengueNews %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, Headline)
# A tibble: 217 x 4
   Serial Date  Newscontent                                                                                                                                             word      
    <dbl> <chr> <chr>                                                                                                                                                   <chr>     
 1    216 43727 "The unofficial death toll is reported to be over 157, so far\r\n\r\n\r\nA total of 491 dengue patients have been admitted to different hospitals acro… dghs      
 2    216 43727 "The unofficial death toll is reported to be over 157, so far\r\n\r\n\r\nA total of 491 dengue patients have been admitted to different hospitals acro… 491       
 3    216 43727 "The unofficial death toll is reported to be over 157, so far\r\n\r\n\r\nA total of 491 dengue patients have been admitted to different hospitals acro… more      
 4    216 43727 "The unofficial death toll is reported to be over 157, so far\r\n\r\n\r\nA total of 491 dengue patients have been admitted to different hospitals acro… hospitali…
 5    216 43727 "The unofficial death toll is reported to be over 157, so far\r\n\r\n\r\nA total of 491 dengue patients have been admitted to different hospitals acro… for       
 6    216 43727 "The unofficial death toll is reported to be over 157, so far\r\n\r\n\r\nA total of 491 dengue patients have been admitted to different hospitals acro… dengue    
 7    216 43727 "The unofficial death toll is reported to be over 157, so far\r\n\r\n\r\nA total of 491 dengue patients have been admitted to different hospitals acro… in        
 8    216 43727 "The unofficial death toll is reported to be over 157, so far\r\n\r\n\r\nA total of 491 dengue patients have been admitted to different hospitals acro… 24hrs     
 9    215 43725 "The unofficial death toll is reported to be over 157, so far\r\n\r\n\r\nA fifth-grader schoolgirl has died of dengue fever at Dhaka Medical College a… 1         
10    215 43725 "The unofficial death toll is reported to be over 157, so far\r\n\r\n\r\nA fifth-grader schoolgirl has died of dengue fever at Dhaka Medical College a… more      
# … with 207 more rows
```

---

If we change the column class to another `class` `factor`, it would fail

```
library(dplyr)
DengueNews %>%
   mutate(Headline = factor(Headline)) %>%
   unnest_tokens(word, Healine)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have followed your instructions. The class for Headline is showing "character". However, I am getting the following error message:  no applicable method for 'unnest_tokens_' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: @BangladeshiVoice  What are the package versions?  I used `packageVersion('tidytext')
[1] ‘0.2.1’`

Comment: I used 0.2.2 version of the package. Your instruction was helpful and it worked after I restarted from scratch and set up a new local directory. THANKS A LOT. Really appreciate your help. I spent an entire day and couldn't figure out a solution. This is also my first post in Stack Overflow and I am so thankful to the community members like you!